# Why can't hostapd service start AP configured in the 5 GHz band using Intel AX200 based adapter?

Tags: wifi, intel, iwlwifi, hostapd, access-point

I am trying to set up an AP using the following configuration:

- Wi-Fi adapter: TP-Link AX3000 (Intel AX200 based)
- Operating system: Ubuntu Server 20.10 (groovy)
- Kernel version: 5.8.0-44-generic
- Firmware: iwlwifi-cc-a0-55.ucode
- AP service: hostapd v2.9 (tried the custom-build from the latest source code as well)

I have two almost identical setups in Canada and France. The one in Canada - works, the other one - no. As I tried to exclude any software configuration discrepancy, I ended up suspecting that this problem is somehow related to the regulatory domain. Below are the details from the failing setup.

As this setup is located in France, I set the regulatory domain respectively:

```
$ sudo iw reg set FR
```

Verifying it I get the following (initially):

```
$ sudo iw reg set
global
country FR: DFS-ETSI
    (2400 - 2483 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5150 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW
    (5250 - 5350 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), NO-OUTDOOR, DFS, AUTO-BW
    (5470 - 5725 @ 160), (N/A, 26), (0 ms), DFS
    (5725 - 5875 @ 80), (N/A, 13), (N/A)
    (57000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)
 
phy#10 (self-managed)
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2437 @ 40), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ
    (2422 - 2462 @ 40), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ
    (2447 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ
    (5170 - 5190 @ 160), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5190 - 5210 @ 160), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5210 - 5230 @ 160), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5230 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5270 @ 160), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5270 - 5290 @ 160), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5290 - 5310 @ 160), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5310 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5510 @ 240), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5510 - 5530 @ 240), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5530 - 5550 @ 240), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5550 - 5570 @ 240), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5570 - 5590 @ 240), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5590 - 5610 @ 240), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5610 - 5630 @ 240), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5630 - 5650 @ 240), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5650 - 5670 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5670 - 5690 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5690 - 5710 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5710 - 5730 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5755 @ 80), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5755 - 5775 @ 80), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5775 - 5795 @ 80), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5795 - 5815 @ 80), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5815 - 5835 @ 20), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
```

To set the country value for the phy#10 interface, I trigger scanning with the following command:

```
$ sudo iw dev wlp3s0 scan
```

Then I verify the regulatory settings again to confirm that adapter determines it correctly:

```
$ sudo iw reg get    
global
    country FR: DFS-ETSI
        (2400 - 2483 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
        (5150 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW
        (5250 - 5350 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), NO-OUTDOOR, DFS, AUTO-BW
        (5470 - 5725 @ 160), (N/A, 26), (0 ms), DFS
        (5725 - 5875 @ 80), (N/A, 13), (N/A)
        (57000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)
     
    phy#10 (self-managed)
    country FR: DFS-UNSET
        (2402 - 2437 @ 40), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ
        (2422 - 2462 @ 40), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ
        (2447 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ
        (5170 - 5190 @ 160), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5190 - 5210 @ 160), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5210 - 5230 @ 160), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5230 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5250 - 5270 @ 160), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5270 - 5290 @ 160), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5290 - 5310 @ 160), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5310 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5490 - 5510 @ 240), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5510 - 5530 @ 240), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5530 - 5550 @ 240), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5550 - 5570 @ 240), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5570 - 5590 @ 240), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5590 - 5610 @ 240), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5610 - 5630 @ 240), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5630 - 5650 @ 240), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5650 - 5670 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5670 - 5690 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5690 - 5710 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5710 - 5730 @ 80), (6, 22), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ, PASSIVE-SCAN
        (5735 - 5755 @ 80), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-160MHZ
        (5755 - 5775 @ 80), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ
        (5775 - 5795 @ 80), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-160MHZ
        (5795 - 5815 @ 80), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-160MHZ
        (5815 - 5835 @ 20), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ
```

At this moment, `iw list` gives the following output (trunkated to minimize content):

```
Frequencies:
    * 5180 MHz [36] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
    * 5200 MHz [40] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
    * 5220 MHz [44] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
    * 5240 MHz [48] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
    * 5260 MHz [52] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
    * 5280 MHz [56] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
    * 5300 MHz [60] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
    * 5320 MHz [64] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
    * 5340 MHz [68] (disabled)
    * 5360 MHz [72] (disabled)
    * 5380 MHz [76] (disabled)
    * 5400 MHz [80] (disabled)
    * 5420 MHz [84] (disabled)
    * 5440 MHz [88] (disabled)
    * 5460 MHz [92] (disabled)
    * 5480 MHz [96] (disabled)
    * 5500 MHz [100] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
    * 5520 MHz [104] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
    * 5540 MHz [108] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
    * 5560 MHz [112] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
    * 5580 MHz [116] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
    * 5600 MHz [120] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
    * 5620 MHz [124] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
    * 5640 MHz [128] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
    * 5660 MHz [132] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
    * 5680 MHz [136] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
    * 5700 MHz [140] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
    * 5720 MHz [144] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
    * 5745 MHz [149] (22.0 dBm)
    * 5765 MHz [153] (22.0 dBm)
    * 5785 MHz [157] (22.0 dBm)
    * 5805 MHz [161] (22.0 dBm)
    * 5825 MHz [165] (22.0 dBm)
    * 5845 MHz [169] (disabled)
    * 5865 MHz [173] (disabled)
    * 5885 MHz [177] (disabled)
    * 5905 MHz [181] (disabled)
```

With the following `hostapd.conf`:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd/
interface=wlan0  # overwritten with -i option
driver=nl80211
country_code=FR
ieee80211n=1
hw_mode=a
ieee80211ac=1
channel=149  # 5745 MHz
require_ht=1
require_vht=1
ieee80211d=1  # no impact on result with 0 as well
ieee80211h=1  # no impact on result with 0 as well
ssid=test-open
ieee80211w=2
auth_algs=1
wpa=0
```

I get the following output:

```
$ sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd-5ghz-open.conf -i wlp3s0 -dd
random: Trying to read entropy from /dev/random
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd-5ghz-open.conf
nl80211: TDLS supported
nl80211: TDLS external setup
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:1
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:5
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:2
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:4
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:8
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:9
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:6
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:11
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:12
nl80211: Using driver-based off-channel TX
nl80211: Driver-advertised extended capabilities (default) - hexdump(len=8): 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 40
nl80211: Driver-advertised extended capabilities mask (default) - hexdump(len=8): 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 40
nl80211: Driver-advertised extended capabilities for interface type STATION
nl80211: Extended capabilities - hexdump(len=10): 04 00 40 00 00 00 00 40 00 20
nl80211: Extended capabilities mask - hexdump(len=10): 04 00 40 00 00 00 00 40 00 20
nl80211: Use separate P2P group interface (driver advertised support)
nl80211: Enable multi-channel concurrent (driver advertised support)
nl80211: use P2P_DEVICE support
nl80211: key_mgmt=0x1ff0f enc=0x76f auth=0x7 flags=0x5800530fb5bfbe0 rrm_flags=0x79 probe_resp_offloads=0x0 max_stations=0 max_remain_on_chan=10000 max_scan_ssids=20
nl80211: interface wlp3s0 in phy phy10
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 14 iftype 3 (AP)
nl80211: Failed to set interface 14 to mode 3: -16 (Device or resource busy)
nl80211: Try mode change after setting interface down
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 14 iftype 3 (AP)
nl80211: Mode change succeeded while interface is down
nl80211: Setup AP(wlp3s0) - device_ap_sme=0 use_monitor=0
nl80211: Subscribe to mgmt frames with AP handle 0x55cefdc6f780
nl80211: Register frame type=0xb0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_AUTH) nl_handle=0x55cefdc6f780 match= multicast=0
nl80211: Register frame type=0x0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ASSOC_REQ) nl_handle=0x55cefdc6f780 match= multicast=0
nl80211: Register frame type=0x20 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_REASSOC_REQ) nl_handle=0x55cefdc6f780 match= multicast=0
nl80211: Register frame type=0xa0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_DISASSOC) nl_handle=0x55cefdc6f780 match= multicast=0
nl80211: Register frame type=0xc0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_DEAUTH) nl_handle=0x55cefdc6f780 match= multicast=0
nl80211: Register frame type=0x40 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_PROBE_REQ) nl_handle=0x55cefdc6f780 match= multicast=0
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55cefdc6f780 match=04 multicast=0
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55cefdc6f780 match=0501 multicast=0
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55cefdc6f780 match=0503 multicast=0
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55cefdc6f780 match=0504 multicast=0
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55cefdc6f780 match=06 multicast=0
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55cefdc6f780 match=08 multicast=0
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55cefdc6f780 match=09 multicast=0
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55cefdc6f780 match=0a multicast=0
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55cefdc6f780 match=11 multicast=0
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55cefdc6f780 match=7f multicast=0
rfkill: initial event: idx=10 type=1 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
nl80211: Add own interface ifindex 14 (ifidx_reason -1)
nl80211: if_indices[16]: 14(-1)
nl80211: Do not open EAPOL RX socket - using control port for RX
phy: phy10
BSS count 1, BSSID mask 00:00:00:00:00:00 (0 bits)
wlp3s0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->COUNTRY_UPDATE
Previous country code FR, new country code FR
nl80211: No channel number found for frequency 5905 MHz
nl80211: Regulatory information - country=00
nl80211: 2402-2437 @ 40 MHz 22 mBm
nl80211: 2422-2462 @ 40 MHz 22 mBm
nl80211: 2447-2482 @ 40 MHz 22 mBm
nl80211: 5170-5190 @ 160 MHz 22 mBm (no outdoor) (no IR)
nl80211: 5190-5210 @ 160 MHz 22 mBm (no outdoor) (no IR)
nl80211: 5210-5230 @ 160 MHz 22 mBm (no outdoor) (no IR)
nl80211: 5230-5250 @ 160 MHz 22 mBm (no outdoor) (no IR)
nl80211: 5250-5270 @ 160 MHz 22 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5270-5290 @ 160 MHz 22 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5290-5310 @ 160 MHz 22 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5310-5330 @ 160 MHz 22 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5490-5510 @ 240 MHz 22 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5510-5530 @ 240 MHz 22 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5530-5550 @ 240 MHz 22 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5550-5570 @ 240 MHz 22 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5570-5590 @ 240 MHz 22 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5590-5610 @ 240 MHz 22 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5610-5630 @ 240 MHz 22 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5630-5650 @ 240 MHz 22 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5650-5670 @ 80 MHz 22 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5670-5690 @ 80 MHz 22 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5690-5710 @ 80 MHz 22 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5710-5730 @ 80 MHz 22 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5735-5755 @ 80 MHz 22 mBm (no IR)
nl80211: 5755-5775 @ 80 MHz 22 mBm (no IR)
nl80211: 5775-5795 @ 80 MHz 22 mBm (no IR)
nl80211: 5795-5815 @ 80 MHz 22 mBm (no IR)
nl80211: 5815-5835 @ 20 MHz 22 mBm (no IR)
nl80211: Added 802.11b mode based on 802.11g information
nl80211: Mode IEEE 802.11g: 2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467 2472 2484[DISABLED]
nl80211: Mode IEEE 802.11a: 5180[NO_IR] 5200[NO_IR] 5220[NO_IR] 5240[NO_IR] 5260[NO_IR][RADAR] 5280[NO_IR][RADAR] 5300[NO_IR][RADAR] 5320[NO_IR][RADAR] 5340[DISABLED] 5360[DISABLED] 5380[DISABLED] 5400[DISABLED] 5420[DISABLED]
nl80211: Mode IEEE 802.11b: 2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467 2472 2484[DISABLED]
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=1 freq=2412 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=2 freq=2417 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=3 freq=2422 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=4 freq=2427 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=5 freq=2432 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=6 freq=2437 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=7 freq=2442 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=8 freq=2447 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=9 freq=2452 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=10 freq=2457 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=11 freq=2462 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=12 freq=2467 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=13 freq=2472 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=1 freq=2412 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=2 freq=2417 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=3 freq=2422 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=4 freq=2427 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=5 freq=2432 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=6 freq=2437 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=7 freq=2442 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=8 freq=2447 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=9 freq=2452 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=10 freq=2457 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=11 freq=2462 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=12 freq=2467 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=13 freq=2472 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Frequency 5745 (primary) not allowed for AP mode, flags: 0x20053 NO-IR
Primary frequency not allowed
wlp3s0: IEEE 802.11 Configured channel (149) or frequency (5745) (secondary_channel=0) not found from the channel list of the current mode (2) IEEE 802.11a
wlp3s0: IEEE 802.11 Hardware does not support configured channel
Could not select hw_mode and channel. (-3)
wlp3s0: interface state COUNTRY_UPDATE->DISABLED
wlp3s0: AP-DISABLED
wlp3s0: Unable to setup interface.
hostapd_interface_deinit_free(0x55cefdc67e00)
hostapd_interface_deinit_free: num_bss=1 conf->num_bss=1
hostapd_interface_deinit(0x55cefdc67e00)
wlp3s0: interface state DISABLED->DISABLED
hostapd_bss_deinit: deinit bss wlp3s0
wlp3s0: Deauthenticate all stations
nl80211: send_mlme - da=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff noack=0 freq=0 no_cck=0 offchanok=0 wait_time=0 no_encrypt=0 fc=0xc0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_DEAUTH) nlmode=3
nl80211: send_mlme - Use bss->freq=0
nl80211: send_mlme -> send_frame_cmd
nl80211: CMD_FRAME freq=0 wait=0 no_cck=0 no_ack=0 offchanok=0
CMD_FRAME - hexdump(len=26): c0 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 5c 80 b6 b8 dd af 5c 80 b6 b8 dd af 00 00 03 00
nl80211: Frame command failed: ret=-22 (Invalid argument) (freq=0 wait=0)
wlp3s0: AP-DISABLED
hostapd_cleanup(hapd=0x55cefdc68fe0 (wlp3s0))
wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlp3s0 wasn't started
hostapd_interface_deinit_free: driver=0x55cefc144c60 drv_priv=0x55cefdc6a1f0 -> hapd_deinit
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp3s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
nl80211: Remove monitor interface: refcount=0
nl80211: Remove beacon (ifindex=14)
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=14 linkmode=0 (kernel-control), operstate=6 (IF_OPER_UP)
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 14 iftype 2 (STATION)
nl80211: Failed to set interface 14 to mode 2: -16 (Device or resource busy)
nl80211: Try mode change after setting interface down
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 14 iftype 2 (STATION)
nl80211: Mode change succeeded while interface is down
nl80211: Teardown AP(wlp3s0) - device_ap_sme=0 use_monitor=0
nl80211: Unsubscribe mgmt frames handle 0x8888dd46754e7f09 (AP teardown)
hostapd_interface_free(0x55cefdc67e00)
hostapd_interface_free: free hapd 0x55cefdc68fe0
hostapd_cleanup_iface(0x55cefdc67e00)
hostapd_cleanup_iface_partial(0x55cefdc67e00)
hostapd_cleanup_iface: free iface=0x55cefdc67e00
```

The following lines from the above trigger my concern:

```
wlp3s0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->COUNTRY_UPDATE
Previous country code FR, new country code FR
nl80211: No channel number found for frequency 5905 MHz
nl80211: Regulatory information - country=00
```

Why does regulatory information is reset to the world domain provided that I set the correct country value? Is it caused by `nl80211` driver, `hostapd` service, hardware or something else? I will appreciate any ideas which could provide me with some clarity on this subject.

Comment: if you do `iw reg get` what is the output?

Comment: @D'ArcyNader, It is reset to the initial state with `country 00: DFS-UNSET` value in `phy#10 (self-managed)` section.

Comment: take a look here, it says you have to disable LAR tas a workaround https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=205695   `iwlwifi.lar_disable=Y`

Comment: Thanks. I saw that one. However, as far as I understood, the lar_disable option is not effective in kernel 5.4+ which is my case.

Comment: i'm curious if you use a different reg than FR is it working properly?
i assume yes because of the canada set up you mentioned before.

Comment: Tried that as well. `iw reg set` is effective only for the global part in the regulatory domain list. `hostapd` log still returns `nl80211: Regulatory information - country=00` in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my surprise, the solution was installing the `network-manager` package. No additional configuration was required, not even setting the wireless interface as managed by NetworkManager. I replicated the same behaviour on another system (Raspberry Pi CM4 board with Ubuntu Server 20.04).

Just a note, Ubuntu Server comes with `systemd-networkd` as the default service for managing network, whereas Ubuntu Desktop comes with NetworkManager.

Comment: Hi, so you managed to make 5G works as AP in AX200? Because I still can't. I am from Argentina (so, AR).

Thanks.

Comment: @GustavoA.Díaz , which Linux distributive do you use?

Comment: In this home server, I use Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @GustavoA.Díaz , is it a desktop edition or server edition?

Comment: Desktop version, using KDE (KDE Neon). But I manage the network by using systemd-networkd (not NetworkManager).

Comment: But can you just share your settings of hostapd anyways? It does not matter if desktop or server for this settings in particular... Thanks.

Comment: Apparently, it matters, as you can see from my comment above. Try install the `network-manager` first. The `hostapd.conf` content is also available in my question above.

Comment: Sorry, didn't saw that. The thing is that every available frequency says no IR and willl not work:

https://pastebin.com/UmqPDzPb

I've tried to change the reg domain, to CA for example, but not luck. Every time hostapd tries to run the settings with the interface, the reg domain backs to country 00: DFS-UNSET

Comment: Did you install the `network-manager`?

Comment: As far as I know, network-manager has no relation at all with reg domain, which you can set with when loading the driver (which either works). So, no.
Please don´t reply without knowing why there is a problem with AX200 chipsets and this problem appears most of all since kernels 5.5, because disabling LAR  does not take effect anymore (which means "Location Aware Regulatory"). Thanks.

Comment: install network-manager works for me, NIC model: Gigabyte GC-WB1733D-I MU-MIMO Dual-Band AC1733 + Bluetooth5.0 PCI-E Wireless Adapter

Answer (score 2):

i checked the list and Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz shows:

> AP mode on 2.4GHz (on devices driven by iwlmvm)

https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi

Comment: Right. But why does it work in Canada?

Comment: are you sure the two setups are identical? because "almost identical" sometimes makes all the difference .

Comment: It is a host with Ubuntu Server 20.10 and TP-Link AX3000 adapter connected over PCI-E (purchased locally) in France. It is a laptop with Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 and an upgraded wifi adapter Intel AX200 module (from Ubit) in NGFF M.2 form-factor in Canada. Same kernel, same firmware, same service and config. Of course, I cannot claim that it is identical. But this is as far as I could go to minimize the discrepancy without further investment.

Comment: last idea, have you tried to disable bluetooth? `or users of these devices who have problems when Wi-Fi and Bluetooth are running concurrently, we suggest to disable BT Coex by loading iwlwifi with bt_coex_active=0 as a module parameter.`

Comment: No, I didn't. I might try that next time when I have access to the host. Thanks.

Comment: Configured `bt_coex_active=N` accordingly. It does not affect the result.